# Recoding row values based on current strings

Tags: r

I'm playing around with the Kaggle [IMDb movieset data](https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/imdb-extensive-dataset) to learn R. I've got a joined df with all genres (below) and want to recode them by the first 2 genres

```
# A tibble: 1,257 x 2
   genre                            n
   <chr>                        <int>
 1 Action                         715
 2 Action, Adventure              200
 3 Action, Adventure, Biography    31
 4 Action, Adventure, Comedy      606
 5 Action, Adventure, Crime       229
 6 Action, Adventure, Drama       608
 7 Action, Adventure, Family       73
 8 Action, Adventure, Fantasy     256
 9 Action, Adventure, History      52
10 Action, Adventure, Horror       78
11 Action, Adventure, Music        25
12 Action, Adventure, Musical       1
13 Action, Adventure, Mystery      35
14 Action, Adventure, Romance     110
15 Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi      251
16 Action, Adventure, Thriller    126
17 Action, Adventure, War          23
18 Action, Adventure, Western      61
19 Action, Animation                1
20 Action, Animation, Comedy        2
21 Action, Animation, Fantasy       1
22 Action, Animation, Sci-Fi        3
23 Action, Biography                1
24 Action, Biography, Comedy        7
25 Action, Biography, Crime        41
26 Action, Biography, Drama        84
27 Action, Biography, History       9
28 Action, Biography, Sci-Fi        1
29 Action, Biography, Thriller      2
30 Action, Biography, Western       1
31 Action, Comedy                 463
32 Action, Comedy, Adventure        4
33 Action, Comedy, Animation        1
34 Action, Comedy, Crime          539
35 Action, Comedy, Drama          317
36 Action, Comedy, Family          40
37 Action, Comedy, Fantasy         97
38 Action, Comedy, History          7
39 Action, Comedy, Horror         140
40 Action, Comedy, Music           21
41 Action, Comedy, Musical         12
42 Action, Comedy, Mystery         14
43 Action, Comedy, Romance        110
44 Action, Comedy, Sci-Fi          51
45 Action, Comedy, Sport           12
46 Action, Comedy, Thriller        62
47 Action, Comedy, War              9
48 Action, Comedy, Western         11
49 Action, Crime                  208
```

ie

```
Action, Adventure, Biography   1
Action, Adventure, Comedy      1
Action, Adventure, Crime       1
Action, Adventure, Drama       1
```

becomes

```
Action, Adventure       4
```

thus far I've only been able to remove the subgrenes using grepl but unable to combine them.

Comment: After you remove the sub-genres, use your preferred aggregation function to aggregate using `sum`. You can do it in base R with `aggregate`, or use "data.table" or "dplyr" if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your problem correctly a possible solution within the tidyverse would be this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
# read in the kaggle file from disk (you have to modify it acording you your file location
df <- readr::read_csv(".../IMDb movies.csv")
# one way to go:
df %>% 
  # get the grouping counts
  dplyr::count(genre) %>% 
  # build new colum from unique rownumber to help later
  dplyr::mutate(rownr = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
  # separate your df in rows  acording to the comma in genre
  tidyr::separate_rows(genre, sep = ", ") %>% 
  # group by the helping rownumber create above
  dplyr::group_by(rownr) %>% 
  # build a second helping rownumber inside the groups
  dplyr::mutate(grpnr = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
  # remove all with nr 3 (after the second comma)
  dplyr::filter(grpnr < 3) %>% 
  # colapse back to coma separate line
  dplyr::summarise(genre = paste0(genre, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  # remove the grouping (safer)
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  # count again by the new genre
  dplyr::count(genre)
```

Much simpler with the same packages would be this option:

```
df %>% 
  # build the counts per genre
  dplyr::count(genre) %>% 
  # separate by comma in colums
  tidyr::separate(genre, c("Genre_1","Genre_2", "Genre_3"), ", ") %>% 
  # count by the first to genre columns
  dplyr::count(Genre_1, Genre_2)
  # you could use tidyr::unite() here if you want to paste the Genre columns back again
```

Comment: This absolutely did the trick and lead me down a path of docs to read.

Comment: @electiondaze please upvote my response or acept it for other to know this problem has been solved... If you have further questions please do not hesitate to contact me here, normally I am online at least once a day https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: new to SF. accepted and will upvote when I have the required rep. Ty for the solution.